# how to change samba client windows 7 user access samba password, user site?

Tags: linux, centos, samba

I was configured samba sharing server centos 6.6. I created samba sharing server access users, client asked for me. How to reset password to myself in samba user,
i dont no any idea. "can you please tell and help me". How to change samba user password.

Thanks and Regards,
Mani

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `smbpasswd` to change your user password of samba,

Add your username to samba database again like as follows,

```
sudo smbpasswd -a <username>
```

For more information check [man page](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages/smbpasswd.8.html).